# SQL select two userIDs as different aliases

Tags: c#, sql

I am having trouble getting the following task done:

I've got 2 tables:

```
User:
  -uid
  -username

challenge:
   -cID
   -challengerID
   -challengedID
```

now I want to run an `insert into` from a `c#` application with (per example !challenge `user1` `user2`)

now the `SQL` is:

```
insert into challenge (challengerID, challengedID) 
where challengerID = id of user1 and challengedID = id of user2.
```

How do I grab those two `user IDs` and store them in different fields in the challenge table?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: How do you know what users to select? If you already know the IDs why can't you just add them directly? Or do you have some other mechanism to find the right users?

Comment: the thing is its for a bot. and its easier for users to use the mention function than to remember the ids or read them out first. so i gotta do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `join`:

```
insert into challenge (challengerID, challengedID) 
    select u1.id, u2.id
    from users u1 join
         users u2
         on u1.username = 'user1' and u2.username = 'user2';
```

When writing the query, you should use parameters for the names.  Don't munge the query strings with the names.

Comment: Wow.. That worked like a charm! Thanks alot!
also thanks for formatting my text.. kinda new around here. 

again. a massive thanks:)